# Falkon doesn't use profiles anymore

Tags: kubuntu, browser, user-profile

I have changed my Kubuntu from 21 to 22.04 and Installed the Falkon browser again (which I appreciate for its option of creating profiles storing different sets of tabs, great).

I have used the same home partition for the new system and in my *home/user/.config/falkon/profiles/* folder this profiles are still exist but Falkon isn't using them and doesn’t display them in the settings :(
How to retrieve this profiles which had several tabs open?

Comment: I found this on the Falkon comments section, from user Juraj: Falkon by default tries to detect already running session and create a new window in such scenerio.
Use "-r" option to disable this.
Your command could look like this:
falkon -r -p debug

Comment: Kubuntu is a desktop system, thus only provides *year.month* releases (no specialist *year* products, with the *year* format reserved for *snap* only products of Ubuntu).  It's best if you're specific with releases; ie. being clear if you mean 21.04 or 21.10 as it can make a large difference (*it allows exploration of the changes made in `falkon` between those releases which differ!*)

Comment: Thanks, it doesn't work. If I set a particular profile after -p or --profile myone falcon opens a small window: "Please select the startup session:" but there is nothing to select, in the dropdown list is displayed "Default Session(last session)" only

Comment: I can see falkon is not using the profile folder in *.config/falkon/profiles/* - time of modification is not changing. So these info are stored elsewhere...